# Ubuntu 12.10 Unity launcher and status bar dissappeared after installing additional drivers

Tags: 12.10, unity, drivers, nvidia, launcher

I have tried to use additional graphics drivers on Lenovo T530 ubuntu 12.10 laptop. Actually those drivers have not installed correctly. After restarting my machine, ubuntu launcher and status bar has gone. I have tried various suggestions but still couldn't make it work.Appreciate your help to regain the unity launcher and status bar.

Thanks,
Chanaka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal with CTRL ALT T and try reinstall the drivers, if they install and for some reason the bars are still not there, issue these commands; `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` reboot your system and again `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` then `setsid unity` but beware, it will reset your compiz settings. it works everytime for me.

Comment: No problem happy to help :)